# An analogue to the Koszul formula in the "wrong" degrees

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth (closed, connected) manifold, $b\in\Omega^k(M)$, $P\in\Gamma(\Lambda^pTM)$ and $Q\in\Gamma(\Lambda^qTM)$ such that $p+q=k-1$. We denote by $[,]$ the Schouten-Nijenhuis bracket which can be defined as an extension of the usual Lie bracket of vector fields, or by the *Koszul formula*
$$\iota_{[P,Q]}b = (-1)^{(p+1)q}\iota_P(d(\iota_Qb)) + (-1)^p\iota_Q(d(\iota_Pb)) - \iota_{P\wedge Q}db.$$
This (at least a priori) only works for the correct $p,q$, that is whenever $p+q = k-1$. I would really like to know if there is a version of this identity for $p+q<k-1$, and in particular to have an alternative description of the operator $\iota_{[P\wedge Q]}$. Has anyone encountered such a thing somewhere?

Comment: your formula is true for all $p,q$ (but you forgot $d$ in the last term; also, I didn't check the signs, but they are independent of the degree of $b$)

Comment: @user8268 That is great, thanks! Would you have a reference, by any chance? I have seen this case of the formula in a book about Poisson geometry, but the proof is in local coordinates and some conventions I don't really like, so if there was something more intrinsic it would be great! Also, added the $d$ ;)

Comment: @user8268 Ah, I think I found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user8268 pointed out, the formula (de facto with a small modification) is always true. A reference for this fact can be found in the paper [The Schouten-Nijenhuis bracket and interior products](http://charles-michel.marle.pagesperso-orange.fr/publications/schouten.pdf) by Charles-Michel Marle (Journal of Geometry and Physics, 23, 350-359, 1997) at page 7, where it is stated that
$$\iota_{[P,Q]} = -[[\iota_Q,d],\iota_P],$$
where the bracket denotes the on the left-hand side commutator. Expanding, we have
$$\iota_{[P,Q]} = \iota_{P\wedge Q}d - \iota_Pd\iota_Q - \iota_Qd\iota_P + d\iota_{Q\wedge P}.$$
Notice that in my original question the last term vanishes for degree reasons.